# Silver Key and Shining Trapezohedron

Tags: lovecraft-letter

How do the cards "The Silver Key" and "The Shining Trapezohedron" from Lovecraft Letter interact with each other? Specifically, if you are not insane and have both cards in your hand, do you need to discard both of them?

The rules for both cards state:"If you ever have the Silver Key/Shining Trapezohedron and another card, that has a number higher than 4, in your hand, you must discard the Silver Key/Shining Trapezohedron." Both cards have a value of 7, so they seem to trigger their abilities respectively and you need to discard both of them, thus losing the round.

There is no mention of an order of play within your turn or any specific rule in the book. I also looked around on the Internet and didn't find anything concerning this interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discard one of your choice.

[Official answer](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1819669/article/26500000#26500000) from AEG posted on BGG by Ryan Dancey:

> When you're not insane, both cards read: "You must discard this card if you have another card with a number higher than 4 in your hand".
>
> Since you can't play 2 cards at once in Love Letter, you need to choose which you will be discarding.
>
> If you discard The Silver Key, that's ok. You remain sane.
>
> If you discard The Shining Trapezohedron, that's ok as well. Although since you weren't insane, you now become so (you have a card with an insane effect in your discard).

Comment: Note that the official answer continues beyond the quoted part above and goes into some obviously-wrong analysis. But the quoted part is the primary point, and seems defensible. For the rest, see https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1926432/double-7-while-insane